# Changing font family for a paragraph in latex rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

does anyone know how to change of font family in the middle of a rmarkdown document?

I am currently using the following code but it resets the given text to computer modern, it is like it just never finds any other font. please help

```
---
title: ''
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
geometry: left=0.35in,right=0.35in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.3in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
fontsize: 9pt
---
\begingroup
\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{18}{16}\selectfont
\textcolor{black}{tasks}
\endgroup
```

In addition does anyone know which fonts I can use? I cant find a list that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using xelatex, so you can use whatever font you have installed on your operating system

```
---
title: ''
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    keep_tex: yes
geometry: left=0.35in,right=0.35in,top=0.3in,bottom=0.3in
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
fontsize: 9pt
---
Global

\begingroup
\setmainfont{Arial}
\fontsize{18}{16}\selectfont
\textcolor{black}{tasks}
\endgroup

Global
```

[image]